# Declining a value w/o a for loop

Tags: r

I would like to decline (i.e. multiply) a value (first.value) against a vector of percentage decline values (decline.vector), where the first value is declined against the starting percentage decline value, then that output value is declined against the second percentage decline value, and so on.  I assume there is a more elegant way to do so in R than writing a for loop to reassign the new value and cbind to create the new vector, but I remain a novice.

The decline vectors are not sequences like below, this just an example.
Although, is it possible to sequence where 'by=' is a vector?  I did not find anything in the ?seq that suggests it is possible.

Whereby:

```
first.value <- 100

decline.vector <- c(0.85, 0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 0.975)
```

Desired output:

```
[100] 85, 75.5, 70.763, 67.224, 65.544
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `Reduce` function in base R

```
first.value <- 100    
decline.vector <- c(0.85, 0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 0.975)    
Reduce(`*`, decline.vector, first.value, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1] 100.00000  85.00000  76.50000  70.76250  67.22437  65.54377
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `cumprod`

```
first.value * cumprod(c(1, decline.vector))
# [1] 100.00000  85.00000  76.50000  70.76250  67.22438  65.54377
```

If you don't want `first.value` to be the first element of the output, then do

```
first.value * cumprod(decline.vector)
# [1] 85.00000 76.50000 70.76250 67.22438 65.54377
```